# ComboBox selection unrecognized

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

My code snipet looks like :

```
<s:HGroup horizontalAlign="center">
    <s:Label text="Anul : " paddingTop="5"/>
    <s:ComboBox id="yearsCb" change="yearsCb_changeHandler(event)" labelField="year"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

Also, in my code, after I open a popup, I encounter the following code :

```
trace(yearsCb.selectedItem.year);
```

that throws the infamous error :

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>       at Function/netcom.vort3x.agr_reg.client.builders.chapters.cont....

Do you have idea about the reason for that error and how to prevent it?

N.B. The code that triggers this error is as a result for click handler. If before encountering this error  change the selection on my yearsCb, everithing is fine.

EDIT:

I forget to specify that this error is thrown when it is a selected item in my ComboBox. It seem that after container that holds the ComboBox loses the focus, it doesn't recognize it's ComboBox child as having a selected item anyway (this problem arise only after the modal popup close.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend the `ComboBox` control to store the `selectedItem` object in a variable when an item is picked from the popup or you could store that value outside of the control in a variable somewhere else in your app so it can be referenced later.

Also, if the `ComboBox`'s `dataProvider` is created dynamically or destroyed after the popup closes, you'll want to store the `selectedItem` using `ObjectUtil.copy` since the original item your variable was referencing would have been destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

you can prevent it using:

```
if(yearsCb.selectedItem != null){

}
```

Comment: You can also use `if(yearsCb.selectedItem) { }`. It's just a matter of preference. :)

Comment: The problem is that there is a selected item, by it is not recognized! I forget to specify that!